# ‘Perfect’ one-arm push-ups

Tags: training, exercise-technique, push-ups

In the video below, the guy does a perfect one-arm push-up: no bending of the body, chest to the ground, the body in perfect line, and with legs at shoulder width.

https://youtu.be/IkG8rCCXnE8

I was wondering if it was efficient to train this movement with partial motions by progressively increasing our range of motion while always keeping the same perfect form.

I can do 25 ‘ugly’ one-arm push-ups per side, but I struggle with 1 partial—not even to 90 degrees with ‘perfect’ form.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know which is the weak link in your attempt to do a perfect one-arm pushup?

How you train for this depends heavily on what's holding you back from doing it. If you can do 25 'ugly' one-arm pushups, you probably have the chest/shoulder strength to do one single perfect one-arm pushup. The issue might actually lie elsewhere, for example the core strength.

By widening your legs, which is what most people do during a one-arm pushup, you create a more stable base to work with, move your legs closer and it becomes more and more about core strength.

Another possible factor might be tricep strength, but as you said you can do multiple one-arm pushups I doubt that is the problem.